# Как через FileDialog открыть картинку и поместить ее в Image в QML?

Tags: qt, изображения, qml

Как через FileDialog открыть картинку и поместить ее в Image в QML?

Answer (score 0):

```
ApplicationWindow {
    Image {
        id: image1
    }
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        selectMultiple : false
        onAccepted: {
            image1.source = fileDialog.fileUrl
        }
        Component.onCompleted: visible = true
    }
}
```